# Streaming response in Feathers

Tags: feathersjs, node-streams

In Express, streaming responses are easy to implement since `res` is a stream object.

Inside a Feathers custom service method, however, how can I stream something as a response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to implement a [custom response format](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#app-configure-express-rest-formatter) which pipes `res.data` if it is a stream, and then resolve your service method with a stream. There is also a discussion about streaming data [here](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/384).

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I'll try and if it works I'll accept this answer. However something doesn't seem right; if the service itself doesn't call `res.send`, what does? I don't remember registering any middleware that would after the services; only notFoundHandler, logger, and errorHandler. And if the service itself calls `res.send` and I add a middleware after it, isn't it too late? So what's sending `res.data` for me, if it's not the service middleware itself?

Comment: Just to clarify for those who might have the same question I had: It seems to me that Feathers automatically inserts a data-sending middleware after every `app.use` call, or at least the ones that include a service middleware. Therefore, if you add a middleware like `app.use(route, myService, myMiddleware)`), but `myMiddleware` never calls `next`, Feathers' default data-sending middleware is never invoked and so `myMiddleware` can have "the last say" regarding `res`. @daff, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yep that's it. The custom response handler is basically the middleware that gets automatically inserted but if you register your own before on a per-service level that does the same thing that'll work just as well.

Comment: @Daff In this scenario: `app.use(route, myService, myMiddleware)`. Is there any way how to pass through a hook that was changed in myService hooks? I mean if i loaded something to hook.params during authentication in myService, how can i read it in myMiddleware?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [custom service middleware](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#custom-service-middleware) before or after a specific service, and then you can use `res`.

Example:

```
const todoService = {
  async get(id) {
    return {
      id,
      description: `You have to do ${id}!`
    };
  }
};

function streamResponse(req, res, next) {
  res.write('Streams are awesome!');
  res.end;
}

app.use('/todos', todoService, streamResponse);
```